# How do you get yuan usb dvb-t tuner to work in ubuntu?

Tags: usb, tv-tuner, dvb-t

The key problem I am having is that there appears to be no information on this specific tuner available. It is a usb dvb-t/atsc tuner, and that is all the information I could find, excluding that it is made by the YUAN High-Tech Development Co.

lsusb | grep YUAN

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1164:1ee9 YUAN High-Tech Development Co., Ltd
```

I have downloaded firmware for similar devices by the same company that is given by the linuxtv wiki (dvb-usb-dib0700) and that doesn't appear to work.

The fact that when you google: "1164:1ee9" linux, you only get 3 results the first of which is related to a wifi driver and is not relevant to this issue, the second of which claims to have the driver but 404's when you attempt to get it, the third of which is a russian page about touchscreens. As you can see none of those links are very useful in regards to TV Tuners.

"YUAN MC782/PD782S DVB-T Hybrid TV AVS Video Capture Drivers" is the name of the driver it appears this device uses on windows operating systems if that is any help. (Information provided to me by Danial Jose)

If anybody could offer assistance on this issue, it would be extremely helpful and perhaps others with this same card will be able to get it working also.

Comment: Install Me TV on your Ubuntu, that may be helps.

Comment: I just installed it to check and it says "There are no DVB devices available". Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: This link may be related to its drivers http://listing.driveragent.com/c/usb/1164/1ee9

Comment: Try to find linux driver for this device "YUAN MC782/PD782S DVB-T Hybrid TV AVS Video Capture Drivers" (source : USB Driver Database/1164/1ee9" class="link">YUAN MC782/PD782S DVB-T Hybrid TV AVS Video Capture Drivers)

Comment: When you search for that and linux you get the single result which is the driveragent website which is the one that 404's as the the link it has contains nothing, however numerous other sites have drivers for multiple windows versions.

Comment: These are the information about Yuan DVB in http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/DVB-T_PCI_Cards#Yuan

Comment: They are for PCI cards mine is a usb device. And I have checked linuxtv and found no information specific to the MC782/PD782S card and the firmware for the other usb cards does not seem to work for this device.

Comment: I made contact with Yuan yesterday regarding the availability of a Linux driver for this particular tuner (My Toshiba p870 Notebook has it inbuilt unfortunately) and Yuan advised me that they do not have any Linux drivers for this Tuner, only the Windows drivers. So no help there unfortunately.